# Игнорирует scanf при повторном вызове

Tags: c

Программа конвертирует температуру из Цельсия в Фаренгейт.
Во время первого использования `scanf()` нужно ввести большую или маленькую букву `с`. Тут все проходит нормально, но второй раз программа не задерживается на следующем `scanf()` и сразу начинает считать.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char bez;
    int i;
    int far;

    printf("Choose the Skala. Enter:\n`C` for Celsius \n`F` for Fahrenheit \n`D` for Delisle \n`K` for Kelvin \n`R` for Rankine \n Enter the letter here --> ");
    scanf("%[^cC]",&bez);

    printf("You've chosen Celsius\n");
    printf ("Enter a value to be converted = ");

    p = scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("%d\n",p);

    far = i*1.8+32;
    printf("%d Celsius = %d Fahrenheit\n", i, far);

    return 0;
}
```

Идеи?

Comment: *"Я в инете пошарила"* -- а надо было прямо тут искать, хотя бы по тегу `C` пролистать вопросы. Один и тот же вопрос про `scanf()` всплывает здесь в последнее время почти через день...

Comment: Если серьезно, то или написать просто `scanf("%c", &bez);` и **вводить данные в программу без ошибок** (ученический вариант) или читать пользовательский ввод построчно, используя `fgets()` (или GNU `getline()`), анализировать эти строки и при ошибках ввода просить пользователя повторить его.

Comment: @avp, а чем `%c` мешает анализу ошибок?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ничем. Просто при ошибке ввода все равно придется читать всю строку.

Comment: @avp, зачем? `while (scanf("%c", &bez), c!='C' && c!='c' && ...) ...`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, все равно выльется во что-то типа `while ((rc = scanf("%c", &bez)) != EOF && !strchr("CFDKR", toupper(bez)))
      if (bez == '\n')
 puts("try again");
      else if (!isspace(bez))
 printf("'%c' -- invalid input\n", bez);`, а потом надо проверять `rc == EOF` и опять искать invalid до `\n`

Comment: Опять же, надо решить, что делать, если были invalid в этом `while(...scanf...) ...` В общем, эта мутота уже не для начинающих.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> scanf("%[^cC]",&bez);
> ```

Здесь считывается строка (не символ! - уже ошибка), отличающийся от `C`.

> ```
> p = scanf("%d", &i);
> ```

А теперь число. Там буква `C`, а не число, оставили и поехали дальше.

Comment: влияет ли первая ошибка на то что второй scanf игнорируется? 
второй scanf должен считать цифру, количество градусов.

Comment: @Diana, формально, первая ошибка - это уже UB (если первым нажатым символом был не C), но в данном случае не влияет. В буфере символ `C`, число прочитать нельзя.